# Httacces redirect rule for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I just did some changes on the permalinks on wordpress: from website.com/post-name to website.com/category/post-name

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Now, when I acces old links I get a 404 error.

Is there any .httacces rule that I can apply to redirect old links?